# Why are my reports skipped? - TeamCity CI

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

i cant figure out why my reports been skipped. My TeamCity CI (8.0.x) Log says "167 reports skipped as out-of-date". Is it because of "parseOutOfDate" is false? http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

**TeamCity BuildLog**

```
Checking for changes
[14:53:22]Checkstyle report watcher
[14:53:22]Watching paths:
[14:53:22]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:22]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:53:22]Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[14:53:22]Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[14:53:22]Clearing temporary directory: /Applications/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[14:53:22]Checkout directory: /Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b
[14:53:22]JSLint report watcher
[14:53:22]Watching paths:
[14:53:22]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:22]Updating sources: server side checkout
[14:53:22]Building incremental patch for VCS root: cp-edna-hybrid Repository
[14:53:22]FindBugs report watcher
[14:53:22]Watching paths:
[14:53:22]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:22]Repository sources transferred
[14:53:23]Checkstyle report watcher
[14:53:23]167 reports found for paths:
[14:53:23]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:23]167 reports skipped as out-of-date
[14:53:23]JSLint report watcher
[14:53:23]167 reports found for paths:
[14:53:23]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:23]167 reports skipped as out-of-date
[14:53:23]FindBugs report watcher
[14:53:23]167 reports found for paths:
[14:53:23]/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b/www/**
[14:53:23]167 reports skipped as out-of-date
[14:53:23]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:53:23]Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[14:53:23]Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[14:53:23]Publishing artifacts (2s)
[14:53:23]Collecting files to publish: [/Applications/buildAgent/work/84ee385a4d5ae77b  => PublishDir]
[14:53:23]Publishing [] using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[14:53:23]Publishing [] using [WebPublisher]
[14:53:25]Build finished
```

Comment: where you able to solve this one? I have the same problem at the moment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967041/teamcity-ant-junit-2-reports-skipped-as-out-of-date)

Comment: Hey m8, yes i did. Take a look in your agent work directory like "/Applications/buildAgent/work/" . Any Report Tools (QA-Tool) will report it self in an own report file. I uses phing now to handle all reports. I trigger phing in an own build step "command line" which set up this line: "phing <path-to-build.xml>". Take a look at phing. I also wrote some extensions for selenium and phpLoc, check this out: https://github.com/linslin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem by myself.

I took a look into my agent work directory like "/Applications/buildAgent/work/" on a configured build agent. Any Report Tools (QA-Tool) will report it self in an own report file. I started to using phing to handle all reports. I trigger phing in an own build step "command line" which set up this line: "phing ". Take a look at [phing](http://www.phing.info/).

I also wrote some extensions for selenium and phpLoc, check this out: [github.com/linslin](http://github.com/linslin)

Answer (score 6):

This is what the documentation says:

> The plugin takes into account only the files updated since the build start (determined by means of the last modification file timestamp).

There are two ways to setup report processing. Through the [build features](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/XML+Report+Processing) or through [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ImportingXMLReports).
If you do it through service messages you can set `parseOutOfDate='true'` to ignore the timestamp on the file.

```
##teamcity[importData type='typeID' path='<path>' parseOutOfDate='true']
```